# (C++) K-Means Clustering trouble

Tags: c++, algorithm, machine-learning, computer-vision, k-means

I'm having some trouble with a K-means clustering algorithm. The input file looks like:

4

60 60

23 45

25 11

30 11

...

...

...

There are 4 total clusters, within a 60x60 image grid. The algorithm seems to work, but when it starts over again to recalculate the centroids and change labels, the labels in the grid slowly start to turn to 1 only. after about 5 iterations, all the labels have turned to 1. I've reviewed the code over and over to the best of my knowledge, and I can't figure out why all labels turn to 1 only. Any help is appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    int label;
    double distace;
    Node* next;

    void printNode() {
        cout << "X:\t" << x << endl;
        cout << "Y:\t" << y << endl;
        cout << "Label:\t" << label << endl;
    }

    Node(int i, int j) {
        x = i;
        y = j;
        next = nullptr;
    }
};

class LinkedList {
public:
    Node* head;
    int length;
    Node* scanner;

    LinkedList() {
        Node* n = new Node(-999, -999);
        head = n;
        scanner = head;
        length = 0;
    }

    void insert(Node* n) {
        if (!head->next) {
            head->next = n;
            length++;
            return;
        }
        n->next = head->next;
        head->next = n;
        length++;
    }

    void deleteNode(Node* n) {
        Node* prev = head;
        Node* current = head->next;
        while (current) {
            if (n->x == current->x && 
                n->y == current->y &&
                n->label == current->label) {
                    prev->next = current->next;
                    return;
                }
                prev = prev->next;
                current = current->next;
        }
        length--;
    }

    void printList() {
        Node* current = head->next;
        while (current) {
            current->printNode();
            cout << endl;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

    Node* scan() {
        scanner = scanner->next;
        if (!scanner) return 0;
        return scanner;
    }

    void resetScanner() {
        scanner = head;
    }

    void changeLabelTo(int x, int y, int newLabel) {
        Node* current = head->next;
        while (current) {
            if (current->x == x &&
                current->y == y) {
                    current->label = newLabel;
                }

            current = current->next;
        }
    }
};

class KMeans {
public:
    struct xycoord {
      int x;
      int y;
    };

    int k;
    xycoord* kcentroids;
    LinkedList ll;
    int row;
    int col;
    int** image;
    int tracker;

    int getLabel() {
        int x = tracker++;
        if (tracker > k) { tracker = 1; }
        return x;
    }

    KMeans(int clusters, int r, int c) { 
        k = clusters;
        tracker = 1;
        kcentroids = new xycoord[k+1];
        row = r;
        col = c;
        image = new int*[row];
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            image[i] = new int[col];

    }

    ~KMeans() {
        delete [] kcentroids;
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            delete [] image[i];
        delete [] image;

        cout << "Called!" << endl;
    }

    void displayImage() {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                if (image[i][j] == 0) cout << " ";
                else { cout << image[i][j]; }
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    void imageOutput() {
        for (int i = 0; i < ll.length; i++) {
            Node* n = ll.scan();
            if (n) {
                image[n->x][n->y] = n->label;
            }
        }
        displayImage();
    }

    void computeCentroids() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
            kcentroids[i].x = 0;
            kcentroids[i].y = 0;
        }

        int* count = new int[k+1];
        for (int i  = 0; i < ll.length; i++) {
            Node* n = ll.scan();
            if (n) {
                kcentroids[n->label].x += n->x;
                kcentroids[n->label].y += n->y;
                count[n->label]++;
            }
        }

        cout << endl;

        for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
            kcentroids[i].x = kcentroids[i].x / count[i];
            kcentroids[i].y = kcentroids[i].y / count[i];

            /*
             * i - label
             * 6 - 4
             * 7 - 3
             * 8 - 2
             * 9 - 1
             */
            //image[kcentroids[i].x][kcentroids[i].y] = 10-i;
        }


        delete [] count;
    }

    void computeDistanceAndSetLabels() {
        for (int i = 0; i < ll.length; i++) {
            int minLabel = 0;
            double min = 99999.0;
            Node* n = ll.scan();
            for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++) {
                double m = 0.0;
                // distance formula
                m = sqrt(pow(n->x-kcentroids[j].x, 2) + pow(n->y-kcentroids[j].y,2));
                if (m < min) {
                    min = m;
                    minLabel = j;
                }
            }
            cout << i << " " << n->x << " " << n->y << " " << n->label << " ";
            n->label = minLabel;
            cout << minLabel << " " << n->label <<endl;
        }
    }

    void startClustering() {
        // more than 2 starts showing 1 take over all labels, 
        // this is to be changed to something better however
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            ll.resetScanner();
            imageOutput();
            ll.resetScanner();
            computeCentroids();
            ll.resetScanner();
            computeDistanceAndSetLabels();
            ll.resetScanner();
            imageOutput();
       }
    }
};

Node* createNode(int x, int y, int k) {
    Node* n = new Node(x, y);
    n->label = k;
    return n;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 4) {
        cout << "Please start program with: program in.txt out1.txt out2.txt" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    ifstream in(argv[1]);
    if (!in) {
        cout << "File: " << argv[1] << " could not be read" << endl;
        return -2;
    }

    int k, rows, cols;
    in >> k;
    in >> rows;
    in >> cols;
    cout << k << " " << rows << " " << cols << endl;

    KMeans km(k, rows, cols);
    km.displayImage();

    LinkedList ll;
    int num;
    while (in >> num) {
        int num2;
        in >> num2;
        ll.insert(createNode(num, num2, km.getLabel()));
    }
    km.ll = ll;
    km.ll.printList();
    km.startClustering();
    km.displayImage();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a pretty hefty piece of code, but for a start, your centroids shouldn't use `ints` for their positions. Otherwise the addition and division is just going to truncate/floor the value. There you want to use `floats` or `doubles`.

Comment: It is, but I didn't know what to cut out without being asked what is x, with X being something I cut out. We were asked to use int for our centroid specification.

Comment: Not just for final output? We could print the final results as integers, but using integers to compute the new centroid positions could be quite problematic (ex: not causing the centroids to move at all in some cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not initializing your counts to zero in computeCentroids(), which results in undefined behaviour. Zero them along with your centroids:

```
int* count = new int[k+1];
for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
    kcentroids[i].x = 0;
    kcentroids[i].y = 0;
    count[i] = 0;
}
```

You can also zero int arrays when you new them like this:

```
int* count = new int[k+1]();
```

Comment: That's really useful and it fixed my problem! Thank you very much!